# Dual Monitor RDP Client For Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have a Windows Hyper-V Server setup. On the Hyper-V Server we have Windows 7 Pro 32 Bit installed. On Ubuntu it comes with [Remmina](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/remmina/) RDP client by default. I like the default RDP client, however I can't use two monitors with it. Both monitors are installed on my Ubuntu 13.10 32 Bit system. Both monitors work great inside Ubuntu, I just need them both to work with an RDP client. Is there any other RDP client that will work with two monitors? Or can I configure remmina to work with them both?

Answer (score 2):

From [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344103/how-do-i-use-dual-monitors-with-remmina-remote-desktop-client):

You can use FreeRDP >= 1.1 from terminal:

`xfreerdp /multimon /u:[username[ /v:[server_address:server_port]`